# height auto not working in many div

Tags: css, html

I have this html code

```
<section id="sec" style="height:auto">
  <div id="wrap">

     <div id="con">
     <h1>....</h1>
          <div id="col1">
                 <p>... long texts ...</p>
          </div>
          <div id="col2">
                 <p>... long texts ...</p>
          </div>
     </div>

  </div>
</section>
<div id="buttom" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153)">
   <p>...text here ... </p>
</div>
```

my problem now is that the height:auto of `section#sec` did not work in many divs inside of it...

is there any way that wihout removing any divs, the height auto will be work?

Comment: Make sure your html is correct. I don't know if typo, but <div id="col1"> is there twice. <div ="wrap"> no id or class set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height` is not a property inherited from parent elements. If you want the divs inside `section#sec` to inherit this property, you need to make a selector for it in CSS (or set inline styles on each one manually).

```
 section#sec div
 {
     height:auto;
 }
```

But since `height:auto` is already the *default*, you may be looking for something else entirely.